# when to use lower bound in scala method

Tags: scala, variance, subtyping

I have been reviewing Scala knowledge and have been going circles about the variance/lower bound.

In the *'functional programming in scala'* book, the Either type, it has below signature/exercise (Implement versions of flatMap, orElse on Either that operate on the Right value).

```
sealed trait Either[+E,+A] {
 def flatMap[EE >: E, B](f: A => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] = ???
 def orElse[EE >: E, B >: A](b: => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] = ???
}
```

and the note of the book says

> when mapping over the right side, we must promote the left type parameter to some supertype, to satisfy the +E variance annotation. similarly for 'orElse'

My question are:

1. why do **not** we have to say `B >: A` in the `flatMap` function? we do not need to satisfy `+A`?
2. why **does** `orElse` signature requires `B >: A`?

I understand method parameters count as contravariant positions, so we could not possibly have `A` or `E` in the method's parameter. i.e. the 'return type' of the `f` or `b` could not have `E` or `A` in it.

Maybe I am missing something, in relation to the fundamental knowledge of subtyping/lower bound/function as parameter.

Please help me to understand it with maybe some concrete examples.

p.s. Most articles, about variance or upper/lower bound, I found have only 1 type parameter in the class/trait.

Comment: 1. Flat map can map the RHS to ANY type so we do not have to enforce any relationship between A and B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why do not we have to say `B >: A` in the flatMap function? we do not
>   need to satisfy `+A`?

`flatMap` does not put any constraint on the type produced by `f: A => Either[EE, B]`. This means, for example, that we can have a `Either[Throwable, String]` and use `flatMap` to convert it to an `Either[Throwable, Int]`. Note that the only relationship between `String` and `Int` is through `Any`.

> why does orElse signature requires B >: A

When we say: "Give me the left hand side, or else give me the right hand side" we *usually* want both types to align such that our "fallback", via `orElse`, will provide a meaningful fallback.

For example, let's use the above example and say we want to take an `Either[Throwable, String]` and convert it to a `Either[Throwable, Int]` using `flatMap`:

```
val either: Either[Throwable, String] = Right("42")
val res: Either[Throwable, Int] = either.flatMap(str => Try(str.toInt).toEither)
```

This will work when our `String` is 42, but if it's not a valid `Int`, we'll get a `Left[Throwable]` back. Now let's decide that in case parsing fails, we always want to return -1 as a default value (of course there are better ways to model this, but stick with me). We can leverage `orElse` for this:

```
val either: Either[Throwable, String] = Right("42")
val res: Either[Throwable, Int] = either.flatMap(str => Try(str.toInt).toEither).orElse(Right(-1))
```

This way, the relationship between the LHS and the RHS is preserved, and we receive a sensible value as the result. If `B` was not constrained to `A` at all, we would usually get a supertype far up in the type hierarchy, such as `AnyRef` or `Any`.

One additional thing about the `EE >: E` constraint. Since `E` is *covariant*, if we tried to use it as a type parameter for the `flatMap` function:

```
sealed trait Either[+E, +A] {
    def flatMap[B](f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, B] = ???
}
```

The compiler would yell at us:

> Error:(7, 20) covariant type E occurs in contravariant position in
>   type A => Either[E,B] of value f
>       def flatMap[B](f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, B] = ???

That's because covariant types cannot "go in" to the method, they can only be used in the return type, contrary to contravariant type parameters which "go in", but cannot be used in the result type.

Comment: Okay, I got it. so there is no 'hard rule' requirement for using upper or lower bound or no relationship at all in the methods. 
It is about what 'make sense' in what we are trying to get.

Comment: @MinnieShi Right. Upper and lower bounds in this particular question serve to make type inference work properly, but also to provide guidance as to "what the right thing" to do is. The thing is, since `E` is *covariant*, you wouldn't be able to use it as an input value to your `flatMap`.

Comment: I will study a bit more ```type inference```. Thank you very much for answering the question to the spot, and the comment also made me realize what else I would need to get better.

Comment: In regards to the extra explanation >>>"One additional thing about the ```EE >: E``` constraint. Since ```E``` is covariant, if we tried to use it as a type parameter for the ```flatMap``` function......" <<<
I understood that, I also understood method parameter is contravariant position.....  What actually confused me or misled me was, I thought 'once you can not use E, you had to use a supertype of E, in this case EE'.... hence I had the question why B is not a supertype of A (as I know A cannot 'go in' to the method parameter, so B occurred)....

Answer (score 0):

If `Either` were invariant, signatures would be

```
sealed trait Either[E,A] {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, B] = ???
  def orElse(b: => Either[E, A]): Either[E, A] = ???
}
```

There is no connection between `A` and `B` here.

Now if we make `Either` covariant with respect to `E` we have to add `EE >: E`

```
sealed trait Either[+E,A] {
  def flatMap[EE >: E, B](f: A => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] = ???
  def orElse[EE >: E](b: => Either[EE, A]): Either[EE, A] = ???
}
```

Otherwise if we make `Either` covariant with respect to `A` we have to add `AA >: A`

```
sealed trait Either[E,+A] {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, B] = ???
  def orElse[AA >: A](b: => Either[E, AA]): Either[E, AA] = ???
}
```

Just `AA` is denoted as `B`.

In actual case `Either` is covariant with respect to both type parameters so this is the combination of above.

I guess now it's clear that `B` in `flatMap` and `B` in `orElse` are different.